# Domain Trust Issues When Setting Up TFS 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, team-foundation-server

I am trying to setup Team Foundation Server 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 using a single server configuration.

During the "Readiness Checks" phase of the configuration wizard, I am facing an issue that i preventing me from communicating with the domain controller (which is Windows Server 2000).

> [ System Checks ] TF255435: This computer is a member of an Active Directory domain, but the domain controllers are not accessible.  Network problems might be preventing access to the domain. Verify that the network is operational, and then retry the readiness checks.  Other options include configuring Team Foundation Server specifying a local account in the custom wizard or joining the computer to a workgroup.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=164053&clcid=0x409

After reading the log file, the main issue I am encountering appears to be:

> The trust relationship between this
>   workstation and the primary domain
>   failed. (type SystemException)

I have read in several other locations that the solution to this issue is to:

1. Leave the domain
2. Restart
3. Join a workgroup
4. Restart
5. Rejoin the domain

Unfortunately, I have tried this several times now and the issue persists.  Is there anything I can try on the either the client machine or the domain controller that may help solve my issue?

Comment: Check the event log for more clues?

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that the domain object for your server is deleted from AD when you remove it from the domain. To ensure this, either use a domain administrator account when asked for credentials as you sever the machine from the domain, or manually jump onto AD Users & Computer, and delete the corresponding computer object from AD.

Once you've done this, make sure to wait 15-20 mins so the change gets propogated around any local domain controllers, then re-join the computer to the domain.

Also try renaming or new-sid the server before rejoining it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fix, but a workaround:

http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/10/21/upgrading-from-tfs-2005-2008-to-tfs-2010.aspx

Find in page:
"you can set environment variables that are read by the tfadmin.exe (the configuration tool) when being executed. In order to do this you need to open a command prompt and use "set TFS_IGNORE_VDCACCESS=1" to set the variable. (It would seem there are several TFS_IGNORE_XXX variables that can be read in when starting, this is the one for the domain (DC) check)."